# Restoring Google App Engine Dev Datastore to a Particular State for Testing Purpose

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I am finding it very difficult to populate the development database for recreating scenarios for testing. Is any of the following possible Google Appengine Datastore in dev environment:

- To archive the all the models in some file and reload the same file to achieve a particular state of the database, something like db snapshot.
- Can the datastore generate python ndb statements, for the stored data, which I can paste on the debug console to populate all my models, this is typically available in most of the traditional databases.
- If it has anything to with language of choice, then I need this in Python.

Currently I am forced to fill the forms of my application again and again to get into a particular state.

Comment: the database is saved in a file. Copy/restore that file to update the database. Create a script to automate it.

Comment: Thanks Paul, can you please make it an elaborate answer or do you have some links to share which contains the steps.

Comment: unfortunately the steps/locations is OS dependant. you can set the path of the datastore "dev_appserver.py --datastore_path=/tmp/myapp_datastore myapp" as documented here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver#Python_Using_the_Datastore which should be enougth to get you going.

Comment: Thanks, I am able to figure out the way to store it in a custom location, but still not sure how to put '--storage_path' option to work to find out the current default location of the storage.

Comment: you can't find the default like that. It's going to be OS dependant where the files is. Just search stack for "datastore_path"

Comment: @VivekJha any updates on whether that worked for you?